# Permanent transparent block

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have two blocks in one slide. I need to show the first block, while making the other one transparent. However, I don't want the other one to show in the next slide. I just need it permanently transparent.

Later, after several slides, I would like to do the opposite way around.
I tried `\onslide`, `\only`, `\uncover` but all those methods show the first block in the next slide.

Can you tell me how to do this ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{block}{Block1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Block2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 4
    \item 5
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? What are the "several slides" in between? Are they parts of this frame? Or do you mean you want to use this frame again with the other block transparent after some intervening slides which are part of other frames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two things you might want. Based on your comment in response to kara's answer, I am guessing it is the first you want. However, your use of 'slides' is ambiguous. I think of slides as parts of a beamer frame. So I'm inclined to read you as wanting all of this to happen within a single frame. In case that is what you want, I will include the second possibility as well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frame<1-2>[label=myblocks]{
  \begin{block}<1-2>{Block1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<3-4>{Block2}
    This block will only be shown later after the next frame.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 4
        \item 5
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\frame{
  Here is another frame with standard covering.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<2-> This item is invisible on the first slide.
  \end{itemize}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\againframe<3-4>{myblocks}
\frame{
  This frame just keeps the second block transparent on the first two slides and then makes the first transparent for the next two slides with no intervening other frames.
  \begin{block}<1-2>{Block1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<3-4>{Block2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 4
        \item 5
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @shrief If the answer helped you, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it as appropriate. This helps other users with the same question identify the answer which helped you. Accepting/upvoting answers is the local way of saying 'thanks'.

Comment: ok, its done :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do that ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\uncover<1,2>{\begin{block}{Block1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{block}}
\uncover<3>{
\begin{block}{Block2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 4
    \item 5
\end{itemize}
\end{block}}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this isn't what I want.
I want to have the first block visible, while the second one transparent, and then I will insert different slides, and after some other slides I will reverse the two blocks
it is something like the intermediate table of content, but on some blocks